# In the ven diagram, finding out the number of elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the Venn diagram, the number of elements of each subset of the universal set U has been shown. Here it is noted that U= A ∪ B ∪ C

[image: Vann Diagram]

(a) Given that n (B) =n(C); find out the value of x.

(b) Given that n(B ∩ C)=n(A ∪ B’) ; find out the value of y.

(c) What is n(U)=?

Answers are given :

(a) n (B) =n(C)

x+3+y=y+8

x=5

(b) n(B ∩ C)=n(A ∪ B’)

y=6

(c) n(U)=6+x+3+y+8

But I am not agree with the answer of b. Because according to me it should be 25. I am not understanding that how it can be y=6.

n(U)=6+x+3+y+8

n(A)=x+6

n(B)=x+3+y

So n(B’) = 6+8

So n(A ∪ B’)=( x+6)+( 6+8)=25

So y=25 as n(B ∩ C)=y

Please anyone clarify the matter to me.

Comment: You miscalculated $n(A\cup B')$. Shade that region in on your Venn diagram and perhaps you will see your error. You tried to find  $n(A\cup B')$ by finding  $n(A)+n(B')$, but these are not the same when $A$ and $B'$ have anything in common.

Comment: so  "when A and B′ have anything in common", we have to consider the common things as one thing as we do in union of elements ?

Comment: Instead of thinking about when we do and when we don’t have to consider things in some way, better to understand what the union of two sets means: the set containing exactly those elements of the universe that are in at least one of the two sets. If you can correctly shade in some union on your picture, you should be able to see directly what it equals in terms of the numbers and variables in the picture. Once you’ve shaded it in, it doesn’t matter at all what expression described the set.

Comment: @Steve Kass, i have got ur point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two sets $A$ and $B$, we have $n(A\cup B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A\cap B)$. So,
we have
$$
\begin{align*}
  n(B\cap C) &= n(A\cup B') \\
             & = n(A) + n(B') - n(A\cap B') \\
             &= n(A) + n(U) - n(B) - n(A\cap B') \\
             &= (6 + x) + (6 + x + 3 + y + 8) - (x + 3 + y) - 6 \\
             &= 14 + x \\
             &= 19.
\end{align*}
$$
Hence $y = 19$.

Comment: So how did they get y = 6????  I was going to post what you answered but you type faster.  But how *did* the get y = 6?

Comment: Actually the answer 6 is given in the book

Comment: @BlackSwan: We have $y = n(B\cap C) = n(A\cup B')\geq n(A) = 6 + x = 11$, so I suspect a mistake in the book.

Comment: @Éric Guirbal, l think so..

Comment: @Éric Guirbal, "y=n(B∩C)=n(A∪B′)≥n(A)=6+x=11" this means that n(A∪B′) must have value equal or greater than value of n(A). But here y=n(B∩C)=n(A∪B′)=6 that is less than n(A)=6+x=6+5=11, so y=6 is not possible when x=5.Am i right?

Comment: @BlackSwan: Yes